# iterating through a multidimensional array using CartesianRange in julia

Tags: multidimensional-array, iterator, julia

I want to retrieve all the elements along the last dimension of an N-dimensional array A. That is, if idx is an (N-1) dimensional tuple, I want `A[idx...,:]`. I've figured out how to use CartesianRange for this, and it works as shown below

```
A = rand(2,3,4)
for idx in CartesianRange(size(A)[1:end-1])
    i = zeros(Int, length(idx))
    [i[bdx] = idx[bdx] for bdx in 1:length(idx)]
    @show(A[i...,:])
end
```

However, there must be an easier way to create the index i shown above . Splatting idx does not work - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just index directly with the CartesianIndex that gets generated from the CartesianRange!

```
julia> for idx in CartesianRange(size(A)[1:end-1])
           @show(A[idx,:])
       end
A[idx,:] = [0.0334735,0.216738,0.941401,0.973918]
A[idx,:] = [0.842384,0.236736,0.103348,0.729471]
A[idx,:] = [0.056548,0.283617,0.504253,0.718918]
A[idx,:] = [0.551649,0.55043,0.126092,0.259216]
A[idx,:] = [0.65623,0.738998,0.781989,0.160111]
A[idx,:] = [0.177955,0.971617,0.942002,0.210386]
```

The other recommendation I'd have here is to use the un-exported `Base.front` function to extract the leading dimensions from `size(A)` instead of indexing into it.  Working with tuples in a [type-stable way](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/#write-type-stable-functions) like this can be a little tricky, but they're really fast once you get the hang of it.

---

It's also worth noting that Julia's arrays are column-major, so accessing the trailing dimension like this is [going to be much slower](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/#access-arrays-in-memory-order-along-columns) than grabbing the columns.